# Tracking a shot with focal variation (zoom)

Tags: camera, video, tracking

At the half of my shot (constantly moving camera) there is a focal length change. In my first tests **the camera is moving forward instead of zooming** into the scene. Is there a trick to automatically detect the focal length change?

*Is it currently possible to reconstruct the camera from such a shot at all? Until now I only have found [this proposal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sftrabbit/GSoC_2013/Proposal), but I could not figure out if this is part of blender.*

Comment: You could try using http://www.viscoda.com/en/products/non-commercial/voodoo-camera-tracker

Comment: I don't understand. Is both your zoom and camera location animated? Or is only your camera location animated and you want to make that into an equivalent zoom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible in Blender. There are other pieces of software which can do what you wan't:

- [Voodoo](http://www.viscoda.com/en/products/non-commercial/voodoo-camera-tracker) (*thanks, [someonewithpc](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/3078/someonewithpc)*)
- [Adobe after effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html?sdid=KKQNK&kw=semgeneric&skwcid=AL!3085!3!45694200562!e!!g!!after%20effects&ef_id=VEFOvwAABE8gtNdz:20141119164138:s)
- [Syntheyes](http://www.ssontech.com/)
- [Mocha Pro](http://www.imagineersystems.com/products/mocha-pro/)
- [PFTrack](http://www.thepixelfarm.co.uk/products/PFTrack) (*thanks, [cgeaton](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1853/cegaton)*)

Some of these are a little expensive, but they are all far superior to Blender's tracker in many ways.
**Note:** Mocha is the best matchmoving/roto/cleanup tool out their. by far. (*No affiliation, promise*), PFtrack also is very good at what it does, but it is still a point tracker.

Comment: add also [PFMatchit](http://www.thepixelfarm.co.uk/products/PFMatchit) and [PFTrack](http://www.thepixelfarm.co.uk/products/PFTrack) Both are capable of tracking shots with variable focal length.

Comment: @cegaton I was looking for PFTrack but failed to find it. It costs as much as a (well) used car though. But the object tracking is to DIE for

Comment: @GiantCowFilms - Thanks! How do you know that? Just your experience? Can you add a reference, paper or wiki-link why this is not possible in blender?

Comment: @cegaton - Thanks! If blender really fails to solve this shot and especially in terms of reconstructing the camera, pftrack is one of the best options for sure.

Comment: @poor I know experts (who have worked on open movies) and such who have tried and failed to do what your asking.

Comment: @poor PFTrack seems to be less than I remember... I would go for it...

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Thanks! Of course, but it would be nice to do it in blender. If there really is no option, I will go for it.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Since you have included a variety of software, I'd add Nuke to the list.

Answer (score 1):

the gsoc 2013 proposal you linked to doesn't seem to be included in blender master/trunk yet, so you won't find it's features in the latest version.

You can use a special build from the GsoC 2013 motion track branch though. http://graphicall.org/1063

Comment: Thanks guest! I've tested the build, sadly with no success. There is a new "constrain focal length" checkbox as part of the refine settings. With this you can enter a min and max value of focal length, but when I setup my values it has no effect and the camera is still moving forward like in the current build.